# csv.read inserts empty field after each record - parsing issue

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to parse a csv from string of the following format

```
'"column a";"column b";"column c"\r\n"1";"2";"3"'
```

Using the below code

```
import csv

text = '"column a";"column b";"column c"\r\n"1";"2";"3"'
csv_raw = csv.reader(text, delimiter=';')
df = []
for row in csv_raw:
    df.append(row)
```

However the output I'm getting when running it looks like this

```
[['column a'],
 ['', ''],
 ['column b'],
 ['', ''],
 ['column c'],
 [],
 [],
 ['1'],
 ['', ''],
 ['2'],
 ['', ''],
 ['3']]
```

I don't understand where `['', '']` after each record comes from. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found out that using StringIO like below solves the issue.

```
text = StringIO('"column a";"column b";"column c"\r\n"1";"2";"3"')
csv_raw = csv.reader(text, delimiter=';')
df = []
for row in csv_raw:
    df.append(row)
```